# Syntax error trying to update multiple tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to update multiple joined tables in codeigniter but it is giving the following error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.`carro_id INNER JOIN a ON ac`.`atributo_id = a`.`id INNER JOIN
>   m ON c`.`modelo_' at line 1

```
UPDATE `carro c, atributo_carro ac, atributos a, modelos m, marcas ma
INNER JOIN ac ON c`.`id = ac`.`carro_id INNER JOIN a ON
ac`.`atributo_id = a`.`id INNER JOIN m ON c`.`modelo_id = m`.`id INNER
JOIN ma ON m`.`marca_id =` `ma`.`id` SET `marcas`.`marca` = 'Opel',
`modelos`.`modelo` = 'AMmmmmm', `carro`.`kilometragem` = '12000',
`carro`.`cor` = 'Azul', `carro`.`ano` = '1992', `carro`.`descricao` =
'dfghjk', `carro`.`valor` = '1288.00', `atributos`.`atributo` =
'rapido' WHERE `carro`.`id` = '10'
```

This is my function to update.

```
public function update_carro_query($id, $data)
{
    // print_r($data); die();
    $query =
    $this->db->set('marcas.marca', $data['marca']);
    $this->db->set('modelos.modelo', $data['modelo']);
    $this->db->set('carro.kilometragem', $data['kilometragem']);
    $this->db->set('carro.cor', $data['cor']);
    $this->db->set('carro.ano', $data['ano']);
    $this->db->set('carro.descricao', $data['descricao']);
    $this->db->set('carro.valor', $data['valor']);
    $this->db->set('atributos.atributo', $data['atributo']);
    $this->db->where('carro.id', $id);
    $this->db->update('carro c, atributo_carro ac, atributos a, modelos m, marcas ma INNER JOIN ac ON c.id = ac.carro_id INNER JOIN a ON ac.atributo_id = a.id INNER JOIN m ON c.modelo_id = m.id INNER JOIN ma ON m.marca_id = ma.id');
    return $query;
}
```

This is my database tables and relationships

[image]

The query is generated by the function. What can be causing the syntax error? Am i missing something?

Comment: are those backticks ` really in your update statement as they are shown here?

Comment: the syntax at `$query = ....` doesn't seem right. I suppose (without knowing codeigniter) it could be something like `$query = $this->db->set('marcas.marca', $data['marca'])->set('modelos.modelo', $data['modelo'])->....`

Comment: @Jeff the update sttement is generated by the function, in the $this->db->update... part.

Comment: it looks like (and again: I don't know codeigniter) `update()` expects only a table name, not fields and joins. This is likely why it wrappes it in backticks (which is for table and field names only). See [the manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Comment: I think you might be better building your (not simple) query via [query()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings)

Comment: @Jeff i used your suggestion of building the query and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [update() method](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data) only expects a table name as first parameter, not a complete statement including a join and more. So it'll wrap the first parameter into backticks. This leads to the sql syntax error you have.

Better use [query()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings) to generate your (not straightforward) update statement.